# How many integer solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = n$ with restriction $0\leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq x_4$

Tags: combinatorics

> How many solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = n$ with restriction $0\leq x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq x_4$.

I have seen this kind of questions with $x_i$ odd/even. Or each having a range like $l\leq x_i \leq r$ also $x_1+\cdots x_k < n$ and in many other formats. But I dont know how to cope with this. How to proceed?

Comment: if $x$ can be negative, there can be infinite solutiins

Comment: @Kiran I forgot to put that

Comment: again, i guess $x$ can be only positive integers

Comment: @Kiran It needs no telling that they should be integers.... But as you said .. I am adding that also ^_^

Comment: This is a compositions problem as a starting point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)

Comment: http://oeis.org/A001400

Comment: @MarcusStuhr This is not what I asked .. -_- 
This is finding the total solutions to $x_1 = n$, $x_1+x_2 = n$, $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = n$ and $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = n$. And also without any restrictions -_- My question is totally different -_-

Comment: @RezwanArefin The outputs are equivalent.

Comment: @MarcusStuhr I think not -_- It will count the solutions with 1,2,3 or 4 variables... also this doesn't satisfy my question ... 
Example... $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 5$. In my question .. there is only one way to have such solution that is $1+1+1+2$ But see your sequence .. it is saying $5$ ...

Comment: Do these solutions not count? $(0, 0, 0, 5),
(0, 0, 1, 4), 
(0, 0, 2, 3), 
(0, 1, 1, 3), 
(0, 1, 2, 2), 
(1, 1, 1, 2)$

Comment: It looks like you may need to update your question to exclude $0$ if that is not what you meant. If $0$ is not allowed, then the sequence follows http://oeis.org/A026810

Comment: No... I included $0$.... But how this problem simplifies to "Number of partitions of n into at most 4 parts" ? Btw... I didn't see any technique there how to find the number of solutions :|

Comment: So if you are including $0$, do you agree that there are $6$ solutions for $n=5$?

Comment: @MarcusStuhr Yes now got it ... there are $6$ solutions :) ... But how do I find this?

Comment: You can try one of the approaches listed under "formula" on the OEIS page, or check out some partition number computation methods here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Partition_function_formulas

Comment: I guess you are looking for a general equation, I see a recursion formula here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76684/number-of-integer-solutions-if-x-1-leq-x-2-leq-x-3-leq-cdots-leq-x-r-leq-k?noredirect=1&lq=1 and I have asked a similar question and a guy suggested to use the generating function https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2641729/number-of-integral-solutions-of-x-1x-2-cdotsx-k-n-with-conditions-1-leq-x/2642105#2642105