# Number of integral solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k=n$ with conditions $1\leq x_1<\cdots<x_k\leq m$ for some integers $m,n,k$

Tags: combinatorics

I have known that the number of positive integral solutions of $$x_1+\cdots+x_k = n$$ is $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. Do we have any formula to count the number of solutions of the equation $$x_1+\cdots+x_k = n$$ with conditions  $1\leq x_1<\cdots<x_k\leq m$ for some integers $m,n,k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using generating functions the problem becomes slightly clearer.

If we remember that the generating function for partitions of $n$ into distinct parts $p_d(n)$ with part sizes $j=1$ and $j=m$ is:

$$\prod_{j=1}^{m}(1+q^j)=\sum_{n}p_d(n)q^n\tag{1}$$

since the coefficient of $q^n$ gets a contribution of $1$ for each possible distinct partition of $n$.

Then all we need to do is use some *enumerator* ($x$ say) to count the number of parts. This enumerator must simply *tag* each part enumerator $q^j$ in our product. Hence our required generating function for partitions of $n$ into $k$ distinct parts $p_d(n,k)$ with part sizes between $1$ and $m$ is a modified version of $(1)$:

$$\prod_{j=1}^{m}(1+xq^j)=\sum_{n,k}p_d(n,k)x^kq^n\tag{2}$$

It is also possible to express the product in terms of [Gaussian binomial coefficients](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) as:

$$\prod_{j=1}^{m}(1+xq^j)=\sum_{n,k}p_d(n,k)x^kq^n=\sum_{k}{m\choose k }_qq^{\binom{k+1}{2}}x^k\tag{3}$$

so that you would be looking for the $q^n$ coefficient of ${m\choose k}_qq^{\binom{k+1}{2}}$.

Comment: The last line is $x^k$, instead of $q^n$, isn't it?

Comment: No, but there *was* a typo: the Gaussian binomial coefficients should have an upper argument $m$ not $n$. Generally $q^{\binom{k+1}{2}}\binom{m}{k}_q$ is the generating function for distinct partitions with maximum part size $m$ and exactly $k$ parts. It is easiest to think of distinct integer partitions that fit in an $m\times k$ box and have at no $0$ parts. If you think of it this way it isn't too hard to see how there is a bijection between monotonic NE lattice paths and partitions (basically the partitions are the area under the path).

Comment: I got it. It is still a little bit hard for me to find a formula for the coefficient of $q^n$ in the term $\binom{m}{k}_q q^{\binom{k+1}{2}}$. About the corresponding between the lattice paths and the partitions, I think it is also a great idea. I am trying to consider the area of that box is $m\times k$. And describe the lattice paths by 1 in the $m\times k$ matrix. If so, the area (partition) is equal to the number of 1 in the matrix. I will try to apply those ideas to my problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is no *nice* formula for those coefficients of $q^n$ that I am aware of. The best I can currently do is to use the "roots of unity filter" to obtain a long summation involving complex numbers, which is harder that expanding the polynomial or using it to find a recurrence. Good luck though!

Answer (score 2):

[Too long to comment] Not a simple one, as far as I know. You can start by noting that we must have each $x_i \geq i$, so (setting $y_i = x_i -i$) the problem is equivalent to counting solutions for $\sum y_i = n - \binom{k+1}2$ for $0 \leq y_1 \leq y_2 \leq \dots \leq y_k \leq m-k$. That problem without the $\leq m-k$ restriction is discussed at [Number of integer solutions if $x_1\leq x_2\leq x_3\leq \cdots\leq x_r\leq k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76684/number-of-integer-solutions-if-x-1-leq-x-2-leq-x-3-leq-cdots-leq-x-r-leq-k?rq=1), and there's a recursion you can use. To deal with the $\leq m-k$ restriction, subtract off the cases where $y_k > m-k$; you can do this by another recursion.

Comment: The recursion is useful for me. In my case, I guess we may have $$T_m(n,k) = T_{m-1}(n,k)+T_{m-1}(n-m,k-1)$$ where $T_m(n,k)$ is the number of the solutions with the conditions and supposed $n\geq m.$ I am trying to use this formula for my problem. Thank you.